# Probability that a stick randomly broken in five places can form a tetrahedron

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, mathematics-education, euclidean-geometry

**Edit (June 2015):** Addressing this problem is a brief project report from the Illinois Geometry Lab (University of Illinois at Urbana-Champaign), dated May 2015, that appears [**here**](http://www.math.illinois.edu/~hildebr/ugresearch/Hildebrand-Calculus-Spring2015-report.pdf) along with a foot-note saying: *An expanded version of this report is being prepared for possible publication*.

Below is an excerpt (though, to be clear, *this* question on MO is about finding a closed-form solution; moreover, (a) the main finding in part i agrees with an earlier [**MSE response**](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/359611), and (b) I have relayed the typographical error of "math.overflow.net" to the write-up's corresponding faculty mentor).

[image]

---

The following problem was brought to my attention by a doctoral dissertation on Mathematics Education, but - as far as I know - the solution remains unknown.

I have already asked this question on MSE, where [**the post**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351913/probability-that-a-stick-randomly-broken-in-five-places-can-form-a-tetrahedron) has garnered over 90 votes, but still no canonical answer in the more-than-a-year since it has been there.

Please add or suggest different tags if it seems warranted.

---

Randomly break a stick in five places.

**Question:** What is the probability that the resulting six pieces can form a tetrahedron?

Clearly satisfying the triangle inequality on each face is a necessary but *not* sufficient condition.

Furthermore, the question of when six numbers can be edges of a tetrahedron is related to a certain $5 \times 5$ determinant, namely, the Cayley-Menger determinant. (See, e.g., Wirth, K., & Dreiding, A. S. (2009). Edge lengths determining tetrahedrons. Elemente der Mathematik, 64(4), 160-170. A more recent article by these authors is cited in the comments below: Wirth, K., & Dreiding, A. S. (2013). Tetrahedron classes based on edge lengths. Elemente der Mathematik, 68(2), 56-64.)

Obviously, this problem is far harder than the classic $2D$ ["form a triangle"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2014/if-you-break-a-stick-at-two-points-chosen-uniformly-the-probability-the-three-r) one. I would welcome any progress on finding a solution or a reference to one if it already exists in the literature.

Comment: I assume that for the tetrahedron there is a difference between the marked (where you say which piece is which edge) and unmarked (where you don't) versions of the question. Which one do you mean?

Comment: Perhaps this phrasing is clearer: If you randomly choose five different points on the unit interval and cut at each of them, then you will end up with six pieces. What is the probability that such a process will yield six pieces that can somehow be assembled so that they are the edges of a tetrahedron?

Comment: Does "randomly" mean that the points should be equidistributed?

Comment: I believe the problem in its original statement was meant only as a higher-dimension analogue of the 2D triangle one. Rephrasing from the linked MO post: "Pick five points uniformly at random on the stick, and break the stick at those points. What is the probability that the six segments obtained in this way form a tetrahedron?"

Comment: There are results going back much farther than the 2009 paper you mention.  The edge lengths are basically an N=4 Euclidean Distance Matrix.  Schoenberg gave sufficient results here, and you can see a good summary of the additional "fifth Euclidean property" or "relative angle inequality" (expressed in matrix terms) in any good summary like (https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~dattorro/EDM.pdf‎
).  The volume of the inequality tetrahedron over the entire space of reachable distances (integrated over the probability at each point) should start an answer.

Comment: perhaps it is exponentially small, as the following answer (on distance matrices) suggests: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/123528/probability-that-a-random-distance-function-is-metric

Comment: The unmarked problem looks much messier than the marked problem. Why not do the case where you specify where each piece goes first?

Comment: @DouglasZare Perhaps that would fall under "I would welcome any progress on finding a solution"; in any event, *yes*, I would be quite pleased if there is someone who knows how to tackle the "unmarked" version as well. (Anyone should feel free to edit this into the problem statement.)

Comment: Have you done either the marked or unmarked problem where you ignore the nonlinear condition?

Comment: @DouglasZare The only "progress" I know of on this problem, marked or unmarked, is in the statement here and some of the responses from the MSE link.

Comment: Not quite an answer, but an improvement over the naive Monte-Carlo method is importance sampling. If one picks a Dirichlet distribution with concentration parameter (2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2), the speed of convergence is roughly quadrupled. Only a small improvement.

Comment: There is more recent article by Wirth and Dreiding; Tetrahedron classes based on edge lengths, Elem Math 68 (2013), no. 2, 56–64. I haven't seen it, so I don't know for sure that it is relevant.

Comment: The alternative to Monte Carlo method as a way of numerically estimating the probability is discretization. In general, instead of a continuous uniform distribution we can assume a discrete uniform distribution. Of course, the more points in the support of this discrete distribution, the more precise the estimates. It seems that in this way we can obtain strict lower and upper bounds and not just probabilistic ones.

Comment: When I tried to solve the marked problem with a Monte Carlo method with $10^{11}$ samples, I got the answer $\frac1{79}$ with relative error of about $4\times10^{-5}$. The marginal expected length of any piece seems to be $\frac16$ (rel.err. $\pm10^{-4}$) with variance of about $\frac1{284}$ (rel.err. $\pm2\times10^{-4}$). Perhaps this might be helpful, especially if someone else checks this too.

Comment: @Waldemar We can find P(n): The probability of forming a tetrahedron where stick is broken at n equidistant points ( n ≥5 )and then hopefully extrapolate the results for very large 'n' or even take the asymptotic value as n tends to infinity.P(5) =1; P(10)= ?

Comment: @ARi The problem is if we can get the exact value by discretization. Do you know how to do it in this simple case (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/2014/if-you-break-a-stick-at-two-points-chosen-uniformly-the-probability-the-three-r?rq=1)? I think that strict bounds are possible.

Comment: @Waldemar Created a post for the case referred to [here](http://mathoverflow.net/q/143799/34859)

Comment: What does it mean "randomly" ? The breaking points are independent uniformly distributed? Or what?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I'd hoped this was clarified by an earlier comment, which I re-paste here: *I believe the problem in its original statement was meant only as a higher-dimension analogue of the 2D triangle one. Rephrasing from the linked MO post: "Pick five points uniformly at random on the stick, and break the stick at those points. What is the probability that the six segments obtained in this way form a tetrahedron?"* If you see a more tractable problem under another reasonable interpretation, then I would be interested to see it!

Comment: The Illinois students have put up a video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qFeyBCGviNQ

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for the link. And a "(Dickman, 2013)" attribution around 3:53! Very nice.

Comment: A content-free comment: the answer, whatever it is, ought to be a period. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_periods

Comment: The conditions equal to inequalities given by existence of quadrilateral (4 sides and 2 diagonal).

Comment: @TakahiroWaki If you have an answer, then please post it!

Answer (score 14):

This is far from a complete answer, but it may be helpful progress.

The marked problem, where the numbers are labeled, looks much simpler than the unmarked version. The region of lengths which can be assembled into tetrahedron in some order can be viewed as a union of $6!$ copies of the region for marked lengths, although this can be reduced by the symmetries of the tetrahedron. So, let's look at the simpler case of marked lengths.

There are linear conditions from the triangle inequality on each face of the tetrahedron, plus one quadratic condition from the positivity of the square of the volume. Ignoring the quadratic condition gives us an upper bound on the probability the edges form a tetrahedron.

The collection of $12$ triangle inequalities and one equation, that the sum of the lengths is $1$, produces a $5$-dimensional polytope $P$ which I analyzed with the help of [qhull](http://www.qhull.org/). Given the simplicity of the result, perhaps there is a way to read off the structure more directly. There are $7$ vertices. Four of these vertices give $1/3$ length to the $3$ edges meeting at a vertex, and $0$ length to the other three edges forming a triangle. Three of the vertices give $1/4$ length to a cycle of length $4$, and $0$ length to two opposite edges. If the tetrahedron includes faces with lengths $\lbrace a, b, c \rbrace$ and $\lbrace a, d, e \rbrace$ then the vertices include $(0, 0, 0, 1/3, 1/3, 1/3)$ and $(0, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 0).$ With only $2$ more vertices than the dimension, the combinatorial structure of $P$ is relatively simple, and is determined by the fact that the convex combination (in fact average) of $4$ vertices equals a convex combination of the other $3$ vertices. Much as the bipyramid in $3$ dimensions can be triangulated with either $2$ or $3$ tetrahedra, $P$ can be triangulated with either $3$ or $4$ symmetric simplices. $P$ is related to the normal disks in a tetrahedron.

The volume of $P$ is $1/54$ of the volume of the simplex of edge lengths summing to $1$. This gives an upper bound on the probability that breaking a stick into marked lengths produces the edge lengths of a tetrahedron, although this is far from the $1/79$ observed numerically by Kirill. It is interesting that the quadratic condition rules out a large fraction of the lengths which satisfy the triangle inequalities.

I think the quadratic condition can be added by considering how the surface intersects the tetrahedra of one of the triangulations of $P$. This is much simpler than taking the intersection of a quadratic inequality with an arbitrary polytope.

Comment: I referred to the last condition as quadratic, but it is higher order.