# What is the probability that these four random areas can yield a tetrahedron?

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, plane-geometry

This is inspired by [this problem about randomly broken sticks that can form a triangle](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2014/if-you-break-a-stick-at-two-points-chosen-uniformly-the-probability-the-three-r?noredirect=1&lq=1). It goes in a different direction than [this generalization about randomly broken sticks that can form a tetrahedron](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/142983/probability-that-a-stick-randomly-broken-in-five-places-can-form-a-tetrahedron).

Choose a point $P$ at random inside the unit disk. Choose two directions at random and cut the disk in four parts by the two segments through $P$ in these directions.

> Question: What is the probability that the areas of those four parts can occur as areas of the four faces of a tetrahedron?

It is easy to see that the necessary condition "the sum of any three areas must be bigger than the fourth one" is also sufficient for the existence of such a tetrahedron, in an analogous way as the triangle inequalities.

> Variant: Take for $P$ the point $(x,0)$, where $0<x<1$ is chosen at random. With random segments as above, what is the probability now?

Intuitively, it seems clear that for this distribution the probability will be smaller because $P$ is in average "more excentric". Note that if $P$ is close to the center $O$, both directions must be close to each other to violate the condition. If $P$ is close to the boundary, the condition is violated as soon as both directions are more or less far from the direction $OP$, which seems to be *a priori* more probable.