# Generate random graphs that satisfy the triangle inequality

Tags: graph-theory, mg.metric-geometry, random-graphs

I would like to generate random graphs that might be geometric graphs in some
(unknown) dimension. So I would like every triangle in the graph to satisfy the
triangle inequality on its (random) edge lengths/weights.
I need something akin to the Erdős/Rényi model such as, 
"[The weighted random graph model](https://arxiv.org/abs/0902.0897),"
but with the triangle geometric constraint.

The earlier MO question, "[Probability that random weights on $K_n$ satisfy triangle inequality](https://mathoverflow.net/q/99813/6094)," seems quite relevant,
but I don't immediately see how it leads to a method for generating the
random graphs I need.

So my question is:

> ***Q***. How can one generate random Erdős/Rényi weighted graphs
>   that satisfy the triangle inequality for every triangle in the graph?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure I understand the issues: First you generate an ER (or your favorite model) random graph. The constraints that the edge lengths are in $[0, 1]$ and satisfy all possible triangle inequalities defines a polytope in $\mathbb{R}^E,$ and you are just trying to find a uniform random point in the polytope, which is a well-studied problem, see, e.g. [Uniformly Sampling from Convex Polytopes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9854/uniformly-sampling-from-convex-polytopes)

Comment: Brilliant reformulation, Igor!

Answer (score 2):

I would generate random graph and discard the longest sides in each n-gon violating the inequality.

Answer (score 2):

let $|e_{ij}|$ denote the length of the edge adjacent to vertices $i$ and $j$, then subtracting $\Delta^*:=\min\limits_{\lbrace i,j,k\rbrace}\left|e_{ik}\right|+\left|e_{kj}\right|-\left|e_{ij}\right|$ from every edge-weight renders the resulting graph metric and preserves the variance of the edge-weights.

Answer (score 1):

The following also works for generating directed graphs with non-negative edgeweights $\omega_{ij}$ satisfying $\omega_{ij}\le\omega{ik}+\omega_{kj}$:
if $r_{ij}$ is a random positive value then setting $\omega_{ij}=c+r_{i,j},\ c\ge\max_{i,j}r_{ij}$ renders the graph metric:
\begin{align}\omega_{ik}+\omega{kj}-\omega{ij}&=2c+r_{ik}+r_{kj}-c-r_{ij}\\
&= c+r_{ik}+r_{kj}-r_{ij}\\
&\ge c-r_{ij}\\
&\ge\max_{u,v}r_{uv}\,-\,r_{ij}\\
&\ge 0
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Make an intermediate graph $H$ with arbitrary random nonnegative edge lengths. Now define a graph $G$ with the same edges, with the length of each edge $vw$ in $G$ being the distance between $v$ and $w$ in $H$.